# Polymorphic deserialization with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, morphia

I have a java object with nested lists as properties. Something like this:

```
@Entity(value="Users", noClassnameStored = true )
public class User implements IUser 
{
    @Id
    private ObjectId                id;

    private String          userName;        
    private String          email;

    @Embedded
    private List<ITeam>     anyTeams;

    @Embedded
    private List<Role>      roles;

    @Embedded
    private List<ITask>     anyTasks;

    @Embedded
    private List<IUserStory>    userStories;
}
```

It can be parsed into MongoDB with no problem using Morphia to map. However when I create query

```
    Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class);
    List<User> users = query.asList();
```

it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for interfaces.ITeam
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:76)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:846)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:282)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:193)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:147)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:139)
at controllers.DBConnection.TestMongo(DBConnection.java:120)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for interfaces.ITeam
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:81)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:91)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:105)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readMapOrCollectionOrEntity(EmbeddedMapper.java:209)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:144)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:47)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for interfaces.ITeam
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getNoArgsConstructor(DefaultCreator.java:53)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:72)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: interfaces.ITeam.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getNoArgsConstructor(DefaultCreator.java:49)
... 16 more
```

From what I understand, Morphia is complaining that it can not map Bson objects to embedded interface property. I have tried to add list of concrete objects besides interfaces but it didn't work, threw the same exception. How can I overcome this ?

**UPDATE**: here's my ITeam interface and its implementation by class team

```
public interface ITeam {
    public String getId();
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getName();
    public void addUser(IUser user);
    public void removeUser(IUser user);
    public List<IUser> getAllTeamMates();
    public void removeManyTeamMates(List<IUser> userList);
    public void updateUsers(List<IUser> users);
    public List<IProject> getAllProjects();
    public void assignProject(IProject project);
    public void delegateTeamLeader(IUser user);
    public void deleteTeam();
```

}

```
@Entity(value="Teams", noClassnameStored = true )
public class Team implements ITeam {
    @Id
    private String         id;
    private String         name;
    private IUser           teamLeader;
    private List<IUser>     teamMates;
    private List<IProject>  projects;

    public GeneralTeam()    {
    }

    public GeneralTeam(String   teamName) {
        setName(teamName);
    }
    //...other properties;
    //...overriding methodes etc
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me as expected. Can you update the post to show how ITeam and its implementation classes are defined ?

Comment: Does the class that implements `ITeam` have a no-arg constructor?

Comment: @Veeram sorry I was a bit late. I've updated my post, adding interface ITeam and Team class. The Team class doesn't have all details but basically it should completely respect ITeam interface. Because of time constraint I had to twist around my whole program in order to fix this so it doesn't look like this anymore, there's no more interface anywhere. But I still want to know how to solve this fo future implementation. Thank you.

Comment: @ASutherland yes it does have